# How to retrieve the repeated name value from each siblings or is it wrong?

Tags: javascript

This is my object :

```
var obj = {
a:{ x:1 y:function(){return this.x //works fine},
b:{x:2,y:function(){return this.x // instead of returning 2, it's not returning anything}
}
```

Is there any constrain to give the name like this? Because each one belongs it's own parent right? Still, why is it not working?

Comment: It is working for me. Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/G6fKc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you remove the several syntax errors it seems to work fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/SBpAF/

```
var obj = {
     a:{
         x:1,
         y:function(){
             return this.x //works fine
         }},
     b:{
         x:2,
         y:function(){
             return this.x // instead to return 2, not returning anything is it wrong?
         }}
}
console.log(obj.a.y());
console.log(obj.b.y());
```